# sql full text search CONTAINS() *sometimes* yield no result

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains, keyword

I reproduced the issue on 2 different Database so this might be a generic issue.

Basically we are using full text search on a table, say we have the table customer, it has ID, name, address etc. columns. the full text search is on the name column.

The following script will work for "some" of the rows only

```
select name, * 
from customer 
where contains(name, N' "foo bar" ')
```

If the customer name is foo bar then it will be returned. but if the customer name is "GET" then it will NOT be returned i.e.

```
select name, * 
from customer 
where contains(name, N' "GET" ')
```

This will NOT return the row, but if I change the value of the name to `"GETS"` then it will return.

Very strange, maybe the `"GET"` is a keyword and full text search doesn't like it? I didn't find any documentation regarding this.

Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Why not with --> where name like '%foo bar%'?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL, I know can do LIKE %% for partial match but since I have an index on the name, I want to do faster search with the full text search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is pretty straightforward: `get` is the system defined stop word, therefore it gets ignored during searches.

You can examine words in the the system defined stop list like this:

```
select * from sys.fulltext_system_stopwords where language_id=1033
```

And you can turn off the stop list for your index like this:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON customer SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

Run the above query and try running your searches for `get` again and see if any results are returned.

More info on stop words and stop lists can be found here: [Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search) .

Comment: I have a column that holds some ids separated with a pipe "12|332|5|44". I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why CONTAINS(Filters, '5') wasn't returning any records.

Comment: Yes. Stop list is irrelevant in my case. Turned it off as you suggested.